# SSIS SQL Task Executing on first day of Every Quarter

Tags: ssis

Creating with SSIS Package in SQL2008.

Used Two SQL Script Tasks
"Initiation Job" and
"Update Table" .

I have few Update queries in "Update Table" and I have to update these queries on first day of Every Quarter.

So pls help me what to write in the "Initiation Job"???

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear if you're asking how to run the complete package on specific dates, or how to run just two tasks within the package on specific dates and skip over them on other dates. But either way the solution is the same.

If you don't have one already, I would create a [calendar table](http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html) with a column called `IsFirstDayOfQuarter` that you set according to your definition of what a quarter is. A calendar table is extremely useful in general, and in this case it's handy because a) there's no standard definition of a quarter or when the first day is, and b) you can change the dates easily when necessary.

Then I would add a package variable also called `IsFirstDayOfQuarter` and set it from the table at the beginning of your package execution. After that, you can use it anywhere inside the package to decide if specific tasks should be executed or not, including in [precedence constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141261(v=sql.110).aspx).

This is a useful technique in general if you need to run things on the first day of a week, working days only etc.